# Add numbers in a string array- android

Tags: java, android

I have a string like

```
String str = "102, 308, 409.5";
```

and I want to add the numbers in the string 102+308+409.5 and keep the result in variable.
How can I achieve that?Thanks

Note I was trying to convert the string to string array and then to int array in the below code, but doesn't works.

```
int sum = 0;

String[] arr = str.split(",");
int[] numArr = new int[arr.length];

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

numArr[i] = Double.parseDouble(arr[i]);

sum+=numArr[i];

}
```

Comment: `int sum` and `int[] numArr` - but you want to sum **doubles**!

Comment: Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give this a go:

```
double sum = 0;

String[] arr = str.split(",");
double[] numArr = new int[arr.length];

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

numArr[i] = Double.parseDouble(arr[i]);

sum+=numArr[i];

}
```

If you are going to `parseDouble` you need to put that into a `double` variable, whether that is an array, or just a standard variable.

Comment: My mistake, was keeping double in int. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

ok, and why is the numArr[] in first place :)

```
double sum = 0;

String[] arr = str.split(",");
//double[] numArr = new int[arr.length];//delete this

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

numArr[i] = Double.parseDouble(arr[i]);
```

// sum+=numArr[i];//delete this

```
sum+=Double.parseDouble(arr[i]);

}
```